# Sql server 2008 service broker millions of queues

Tags: sql-server

I am working on wireframe for new feature in our application. One of the requirements is each user has a list of things to process.

I am planning to use SQL Server 2008 service broker to send notifications of to-do items to users.

But with the way the broker queue is working I can't isolate messages for users in a single queue. I can only see after a message is retrieved. However, I only want it to retrieve a message for the user that is calling it.

So if I want to use broker service I would need a separate queue for each user.

Then I would end up having millions of queues in broker service.

Am I missing any feature of broker service that can allow me to have one queue but retrieve messages with a filter?

Can SQL Server 2008 broker service handle millions of queues and is it ok to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Messaging applications in general are event driven, ie. when a message comes it activates a processing procedure that handles the message. Service Broker implements this through the activation mechanism attached to queues. In this philosophy there is no need to filter messages, as the processing always processes 'the next message' in the queue, and the queue is, ideally, always empty. As a result the RECEIVE verb does not offer any filter. The WHERE clauses of RECEIVE are restricted to conversations and conversation groups and this is as a means to help application leverage the [conversation group locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171615.aspx) concept, not to filter our certain messages.

Although queues are nothing more than ordinary (internal) tables disguised under a fancy name they carry some baggage implied that would make having millions a bad idea:

- Each queue must have at least a service associated with it. Services are a bit more heavyweight in runtime cost, since they are associated with message routing and thus they consume start up time (to scan the db and create the tempdb hidden instance routing table), tempdb space (the said routing table) and runtime memory (cached memory structures associated with routing). They would also induce some CPU overhead (for the routing algorithm to decide between millions of candidates).
- Queue can become much heavier 'on their own' if activation is associated with them. Each queue will have a runtime object, the Queue Monitor, that will consume memory and CPU, see [http://rusanu.com/2008/08/03/understanding-queue-monitors](http://rusanu.com/2008/08/03/understanding-queue-monitors/)
- You will need at least one conversation to reach a queue, and live, active, conversations can occur some overhead.
- The queue object is associated with the `RECEIVE` verb and, more importantly, with the `WAITFOR(RECEIVE)`. `WAITFOR` blocks a worker thread on the server and you will run out of `sp_configure 'max worker threads'` long, long before you place a `WAITFOR` on each queue.

Also queue/services are a bit more 'active' from a configuration/monitoring requirement point of view than an ordinary table. There are two problems I have in mind when I say this: [poison message detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171592.aspx) can trigger and disable your queue, you'll have a hard time keeping an eye on a million queues (it can and should be automated, but still). Second is the problem than can occur if, for whatever reason, messages are delayed through the [transmission queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190336.aspx): when transmission resumes having millions of conversations woken up will behave quite bad (milleage may vary, depends a lot on what SQL version/SP level you are as some issue were fixed  post SQL 2K5 SP3).

Service Broker was designed primarily in mind with the problems of distributed applications (ie. to address the issues unaddressed by DCM/COM+, Corba, Remoting and the like). But is it often deployed locally, entirely contained within one single SQL server instance or even database, to leverage the queuing behavior and the activation mechanism. If the sole reason you're looking at SSB is to leverage queues, then I'd say is a 50/50 split between using thew SSB queues vs. building your own user table backed queues, with a lean toward building your own if you have the expertise (ie. you know how to solve the many deadlock issues that come with user table backed queues). If you're also leveraging Activation, then SSB has a lot more appeal, and if you are actually doing remote messaging then is clearly the best option.

In your case, since I hope I made it clear why having million of queues is a bad idea. where do your messages originate (local vs. remote), and why are you considering Service Broker to start with? W/o knowing all the details, I'd say that the best alternative is to have one queue, an activated procedure that processes all messages as they arrive and deposits the relevant information for each user in a normal table that can be properly filtered by each user for its own data.

Disclosure: I am a former member of the [Service Broker team and maintain the SSB blog](http://rusanu.com)

Comment: How about scenarios where you are forwarding messages to other companies (say 1000+)?  Ideally, you wouldn't want a message from Company A blocking messages to Company B, due to a comms issue with Company A?  I'm assuming the solution to this is in the poison message handling rather than having multiple queues?

The issue we've got is that we need to integrate with these companies through a specific web service interface, so we can't use service broker to forward messages to a company queue (which they host) or anything like that.

Comment: @spooner: Actually Service Broker has forwarding built in and the entire service broker messaging stack is designed for fairness, a message not only cannot block other messages but even a large message will be sent interleaved with shorter messages from othe sessions. Poison message handling and queue is about **applications** not about infrastructure. Is the user code, the application, that is unable to handle a message, and that is always, by definition, a bug in the code.

Comment: @spooner: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166098.aspx to understand the built-in SSB forwarding

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to set up to-do queues for multiple listeners on the same queue.  It requires an auxiliary table to track the service broker conversations, and takes advantage of the fact there is a limited filter ability in the RECEIVE clause - by conversation handle or conversation group.

Create a table Listener(ListenerCode varchar(10) primary key, ConversationGroup unique identifier default newid())

This table has a row for each listener.  The listener code or other key is the ID/Code for each listener.  When you need to send a message to a listener, you look up the conversation group and send on that conversation group.  This is specified in the BEGIN DIALOG ... RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP= ....

ConversationGroup is just a tag you can put on a conversation, they do not have a reference table.  (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166131.aspx.)

The listener looks up their conversation handle and receives on that conversation group.  If they not listening, their messages will just queue up.

Once consumed, the message is gone from the database.  If this is a list of things to process for a user, you probably want a persistent list; so I would probably create a Task table, and the message in the queue would just be a reference to the Task table - the queue is just a notification of new items, not the store itself.